# Is it possible to get an instance of IDataReader?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I know that `IDataReader` is a interface so I can't create an instance of interface.

However, it is possible to get instances of `IdataReader`.

How can this be possible?

Comment: You say "IDataReader is interface, so I can't create instance of interface" and then immediately ask "possible to create instance of IDataReader"?  No.  You need a concrete implementation of IDataReader.

Comment: first line i know and confused for second.

Comment: What do you try to accomplish? answering that will make it possible to help you solve the task at hand

Comment: @RuneFS no its just stucked in head.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure I understand. Telling us what you are trying to accomplish is the only way we can help you accomplish that (aside from  trying to read your mind to figure out what the end goal is)

Comment: @RuneFS He's not trying to accomplish anything - he just wants an explanation of interfaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of an Interface. But you can create an instance of a class that implements an interface. In case of `IDataReader` [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an implementation.

You get an instance by [executing a SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx):

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

For example (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)):

```
string queryString =
    "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

using (SqlConnection connection =
           new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();

    // here is your SqlDataReader that implements IDataReader
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    // Call Read before accessing data.
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
            reader[0], reader[1]));
    }

    // Call Close when done reading.
    reader.Close();
}
```

**Edit**:

I assume that you don't understand why it's possible to have an instance that has the type of an interface. That is no contradiction since an interface actually is a type.

So if i would create a class, say `MyDataReader`, that implements `IDataReader`, an instance of my class would be of type `MyDataReader` as well as `IDataReader`.

If anybody would create an instance of `MyDataReader`, he knows that it also implements all methods of `IDataReader`. That is important for [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

Comment: @Andrew: Simple, check it's [IsClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.isclosed.aspx) property which returns a `bool` :) Or wrap it in a [using-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) which close it implicitely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't Know What you Trying to Mean.

```
you mean a concrete instance of a DataReader-derived class,
 such as SqlDataReader
```

IDataReader has no meaning outside the context of a query,

so it's natural to have it being instantiated by the query via the ExecuteReader function.
You might want to ask yourself the question: Why would I want to instantiate a IDataReader? And if I could - how would I initialize it?